# Feeding data into a Siamese Network

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, siamese-network, triplet

For my project I have decided to use a CNN with triplet loss for feature embedding. I have preprocessed my data to create 72xframes windows, I have defined functions that get me batches thereof with an anchor, positive and negative image and I am trying to build now the CNN that learns embedding vectors from my data and updates the weights according to the triplet loss. My code snippets that I have so far are the following:

```
def get_batches(windows_path = windows_path, beats_path = beats_path, batch_size=batch_size):
    windows_list = os.listdir(windows_path) #those are all songs and their npy windows
    batch_files = random.choices(windows_list, k=batch_size)
    windows_batch = [os.path.join(folder_path, f) for f in batch_files]
    beats_batch = [os.path.join(beats_path, f) for f in batch_files]
    return windows_batch, beats_batch, batch_files

#get_batch(windows_batch, beats_batch, batch_size, R, frames, delta_pos, delta_negMax, delta_negMin) -> returns the windows, anchors, positives and negatives for my batch
def get_triples_batch(windows_path, batch_files, beats_path, R, frames, delta_pos, delta_negMax, delta_negMin):
    triples = []
    for file in batch_files:
        
        b = np.load(os.path.join(beats_path, file))
    
        anchor, anchor_index = anchor_beat(b, R, frames)
        positive, positive_index = positive_beat(b, anchor, delta_pos, R, frames)
        negative, negative_index = negative_beat(b, anchor, delta_negMax, delta_negMin, R, frames)
        
        windows_file = np.load(os.path.join(windows_path, file))
    
        anchor_window =  np.zeros((windows_file.shape[0], frames))
        positive_window = np.zeros((windows_file.shape[0], frames))
        negative_window = np.zeros((windows_file.shape[0], frames))
        for frame in range(frames):
            anchor_window[:,frame] = windows_file[:,anchor_index - (frames-1)//2 + frame]
            positive_window[:,frame] = windows_file[:,positive_index - (frames-1)//2 + frame]
            negative_window[:,frame] = windows_file[:,negative_index - (frames-1)//2 + frame]
        triples.append([anchor_window, positive_window, negative_window]) 
    
    return triples
```

This is how I create by batches, so the input of the NN would be an array that consists of 30 rows and 3 columns, and each entry is a matrix.

My model specifications so far are the following:

```
def get_embedding_module(image_array):
    # construct the input layer and pass the inputs through a
    # pre-processing layer
    inputs = keras.Input(shape=(batch_size,72,frames))
    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (1,1), activation='relu', input_shape=(batch_size,72,frames))(inputs)
    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(128, (1,1), activation='relu')(x)
    x = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(3, 4))(x)
    x = keras.layers.Conv2D(256, (1,1), activation='relu')(x)
    x = keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 4))(x)
    x = keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
    #Embedding layer
    x = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
    x = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='linear')(x)  
    #L2 Normalization layer if necessary
    outputs = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.math.l2_normalize(x, axis=1))(x)
    
    # build the embedding model and return it
    embedding = keras.Model(inputs, outputs, name="embedding")(x)
    return embedding

def get_siamese_network(imageSize, embeddingModel):
    # build the anchor, positive and negative input layer
    anchorInput = keras.Input(name="anchor", shape=imageSize)
    positiveInput = keras.Input(name="positive", shape=imageSize)
    negativeInput = keras.Input(name="negative", shape=imageSize)
    # embed the anchor, positive and negative images
    anchorEmbedding = embeddingModel(anchorInput)
    positiveEmbedding = embeddingModel(positiveInput)
    negativeEmbedding = embeddingModel(negativeInput)
    # build the siamese network and return it
    siamese_network = keras.Model(
        inputs=[anchorInput, positiveInput, negativeInput],
        outputs=[anchorEmbedding, positiveEmbedding, negativeEmbedding]
    )
    return siamese_network

class SiameseModel(keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, siameseNetwork, margin, lossTracker):
        super().__init__()
        self.siameseNetwork = siameseNetwork
        self.margin = margin
        self.lossTracker = lossTracker
    def _compute_distance(self, inputs):
        (anchor, positive, negative) = inputs

        embeddings = self.siameseNetwork((anchor, positive, negative))
        anchorEmbedding = embeddings[0]
        positiveEmbedding = embeddings[1]
        negativeEmbedding = embeddings[2]

        apDistance = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(anchorEmbedding - positiveEmbedding), axis=-1)
        anDistance = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(anchorEmbedding - negativeEmbedding), axis=-1)
        
        return (apDistance, anDistance)
        
    def _compute_loss(self, apDistance, anDistance):
        loss = apDistance - anDistance
        loss = tf.maximum(loss + self.margin, 0.0)
        return loss

    def call(self, inputs):
        (apDistance, anDistance) = self._compute_distance(inputs)
        return (apDistance, anDistance)

    def train_step(self, inputs):
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            (apDistance, anDistance) = self._compute_distance(inputs)
            loss = self._compute_loss(apDistance, anDistance)

        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.siameseNetwork.trainable_variables)
        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, self.siameseNetwork.trainable_variables)        )
        # update the metrics and return the loss
        self.lossTracker.update_state(loss)
        return {"loss": self.lossTracker.result()}

    def test_step(self, inputs):
        (apDistance, anDistance) = self._compute_distance(inputs)
        loss = self._compute_loss(apDistance, anDistance)
        
        self.lossTracker.update_state(loss)
        return {"loss": self.lossTracker.result()}
        
    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.lossTracker]

class SiameseModel(Model):
    

    def __init__(self, siamese_network, margin=0.5):
        super().__init__()
        self.siamese_network = siamese_network
        self.margin = margin
        self.loss_tracker = metrics.Mean(name="loss")

    def call(self, inputs):
        return self.siamese_network(inputs)

    def train_step(self, data):
   
        with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            loss = self._compute_loss(data)

        gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.siamese_network.trainable_weights)

        self.optimizer.apply_gradients(
            zip(gradients, self.siamese_network.trainable_weights)
        )

        self.loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        return {"loss": self.loss_tracker.result()}

    def test_step(self, data):
        loss = self._compute_loss(data)

        self.loss_tracker.update_state(loss)
        return {"loss": self.loss_tracker.result()}

    def _compute_loss(self, data):
        ap_distance, an_distance = self.siamese_network(data)

        loss = ap_distance - an_distance
        loss = tf.maximum(loss + self.margin, 0.0)
        return loss

    @property
    def metrics(self):
        return [self.loss_tracker]
```

I have some questions in order to make this functional:

1. Is it smart, since I am sampling my batches from multiple data, to write a for-loop that defines a fixed amount of iterations, in which the model is trained? And if yes, how would such one look like?
2. How do I actually feed my data into the model? I have modified code here mostly found in the web, so I am also not sure if it works in this implementation yet for my data?

Also for clarity, what is the difference between a CNN with some distance-loss and a siamese network? I was reading that a Siamese Network architecture consists of two identical neural networks, each taking an input sample, and producing a fixed-length output vector, which represents the embedding or the features of the input sample. But with triplet loss, wouldn't you need 3? So is my approach with Siamese Networks in order to do what I described correct? Code snippets would be extremely helpful!